# Java SE - Advice RE: storing configuration data

Tags: java, sqlite, configuration, persistence

I'm writing a Java SE 7 desktop application.  I will need to store data such as configuration settings and 2 user accounts (an admin and everyone).  The simplest method seems to be just writing a text file but I don't see any effective means for protecting that data and it is sensitive.  I'm thinking SQLite is probably the best tool for me but I was wondering if anyone might have any suggestions as to something even smaller, more lightweight, simpler -- as there just isn't enough data that needs storing to justify a whole database it seems.

Thanks!
Irongleet

Comment: One mechanism may be encrypt data and write a file with different extension. I feel sql for only this purpose is little bit overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and should) use the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for that. On Windows, it will write to the Registry (so it's different for each user).